# Google Cloud Platform Not Letting Me Add A Billing Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

My product basically revolves around a particular google cloud platform feature, for which I need to add a billing account. Whenever I go to do that, it doesn't let me add it. What happens is I try signing up for a free trial, but when I tell it to verify my card details and send me an OTP, despite entering the valid OTP it still returns me to the exact same page.

I click the start button:
[image: Image of what it initially shows]

Then it prompts me to enter my cvv, which I do.

Even after doing all those things, correctly entering everything, including the OTP it sends, I land on the exact same page. There is no option whatsoever to proceed or anything.

Side note, if it helps I'm in India and I'm using a MasterCard

**EDIT**:
I forgot to mention it was actually deducting the balance from my account, but still not letting me proceed

Comment: Most likely your card is not accepted by Google or does not meet Google' requirement for recurring payments and identity validation. You will need to contact your credit card bank to confirm why payments are not completing. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#supported_payment_methods https://support.google.com/a/answer/3401127?hl=en

Comment: Try adding it later. If the that type of card isn't accepted, there's still eg. Visa debit cards (it's prepaid). And it's hard to verify for us, but you could ask in India, which cards are known to be accepted. Make sure not using Brave browser, which often may interfere with "shields up".

Comment: I have a mastercard, its being accepted because it deducts the balance from my account. I don't know why its not proceeding though.

Comment: Check if the amount is a "pending" authorization. Call your credit card company to find out if they are blocking Google from completing the charges. This issue has happened to me and I had to remove a fraud block put on my account by my credit card. Also, read the link in my first comment (red text) that some cards will not work at all after April 1, 2021. The end result is that Stackoverflow cannot help you solve this. You either have a problem with your credit card or with Google.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: @fullstackslayer Did you manage to get around this? I have now tried 3 different bank cards. Google payment fails telling "missing debit authorisation". But bank clearly tells debit mandate of INR 75000 active for "Google Cloud" and also shared valid mandate id.  Was exploring GCP. Disappointed. Maybe this is India specific issue, but there is zero help or guidance from anyone. Never faced any billing issue with Azure. Also tried contacting Google Billing Support, but that is going in cirlces.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your issue is related to the known issue with creating GCP billing accounts.

Please follow [this issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186210363) at the Google Public Issue Tracker to be updated. Feel free to add comments, CC yourself to receive emails with updates and press `+1`.